# Is the Standard Model an invariant subgroup of $SU(5)$?

Tags: group-theory, grand-unification

It is well known that the Standard Model (SM) gauge group is a subgroup of $SU(5)$:
\begin{equation}
  SU(3) \times SU(2)\times U(1) ~\subset~SU(5)
\end{equation}
This can be easily checked using the [method of Dynkin diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram). Is this subgroup an invariant subgroup such that,
\begin{equation}
g _{SU(5)} g _{SM} g _{SU(5)} = g _{SM} ' \,,
\end{equation}
where $g_{SU(5)}$ ($g_{SM}$) is an element of $SU(5)$ ($SM$)?

**Background**: The reason I'm interested in this is because then its necessarily true that the non-SM gauge group generators of $SU(5)$ can be written as solely off-diagonal matrices and the SM as solely diagonal (this is easy to see by writing the matrices in block diagonal form), which simplifies calculations.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, $$G~:=~SU(3) \times SU(2)\times U(1)$$ is *not* a subgroup of $SU(5)$, but $G/\mathbb{Z}_6$ is a subgroup of $SU(5)$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176544/2451) Phys.SE post and Ref. 1.

We interprete OP's question (v3) as essentially asking

> Is $G/\mathbb{Z}_6$ a [normal subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) of $SU(5)$?

Or in terms of the corresponding [Lie algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra),

> Is $su(3) \oplus su(2)\oplus u(1)$ an [ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Homomorphisms.2C_subalgebras.2C_and_ideals) of $su(5)$?

Here we identify $su(5)$ with anti-Hermitian traceless $5\times 5$ matrices; $su(3)$ with anti-Hermitian traceless $3\times 3$ block matrices in rows/columns 1,2,3; and $su(2)$ with the anti-Hermitian traceless $2\times 2$ block matrices in rows/columns 4,5; while $u(1)$ is generated by the diagonal traceless matrix ${\rm diag}(-2,-2,-2,3,3)$ times an imaginary number.

It is not hard to see that if we consider the Lie bracket (or equivalently commutator) $C=[A,B]$ between e.g. an $su(3)$ matrix $A$ with non-zero entries 12 and 21, and an $su(5)$ matrix $B$ with non-zero entries 25 and 52, then $C$ would have non-zero elements 15 and 51, and hence cannot belong to $su(3) \oplus su(2)\oplus u(1)$.

> We conclude that $su(3) \oplus su(2)\oplus u(1)$ is *not* an ideal of $su(5)$.

References:

1. J.C. Baez, *Calabi-Yau Manifolds and the Standard Model,* [arXiv:hep-th/0511086](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0511086).