# $SU(5)$ Gauge Field Theory, symmetry breaking

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

If I start with an $SU(5)$ gauge group and discover that the vacuum is preserved only by matrices of the form $G$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        A & 0 \\
        0 & B \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
where the conditions on $A$ and $B$ ($A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix and $B$ a $2\times 2$) are: that they must be Hermitian, and the matrix $G$ is traceless.

I don't understand why, if $tr(A)=−tr(B)$, then I have $U(1)$ and if I take $trA = trB = 0$ it is $SU(3)\times SU(2)$, so it means $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176544/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "if $\operatorname {tr} G= 0= \operatorname {tr} A +\operatorname {tr} B$": you already assumed it.

The traceless matrix diag$(2I_3, -3I_2)$ manifestly commutes with all 12 linearly independent *G*s, so it is a sole generator commuting with the full algebra; hence it generates  a *U(1)* by exponentiation, relating to all remaining generators in *G* by a Cartesian $\times$.

The remaining 11 *G*s may now be made traceless by subtracting a suitable multiple of this *U(1)* generator from *G*,
$G'=G-(\operatorname {tr}A)\operatorname {diag}(I_3/3,-I_2/2)$.  Now both the *A*'s and the *B*'s are traceless.

3×3 hermitean traceless matrices comprise the algebra of *SU(3)*, and  2×2 such the algebra of *SU(2)*, commuting between these blocks by construction/posit, above. You are then left with the direct sum of 1+8+3 generators of $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$.