# Hypercharge normalization for $SU(5)$ GUT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lie-algebra, beyond-the-standard-model, normalization, grand-unification

Reading about $SU(5)$ unification, texts says that they use the normalization factor $\sqrt{3/5}$ for weak hypercharges in order to embed SM into a $SU(5)$ group. This implies a new $U(1)_Y$ coupling constant given by

$$
\alpha_1 = \frac{5}{3}\alpha_Y.
$$

$\alpha_Y$ is the one you obtain without altered normalization.

Where did this extra factor come out? Why do you need it to unification?

Answer (score 2):

I illustrate @Qmechanic's complete answer for the **5** of SU(5), as a mnemonic, if you are caught in a bus trip out of internet reach.

Unification means that the 8 generators of SU(3), the 3 of SU(2) *and* the hypercharge are all embedded in the 24 of SU(5), and represented by hermitean traceless matrices, normalized uniformly, so, in the fundamental, $\operatorname {Tr} T_a T_b= 2\delta_{ab} $, a peculiar historical vestige of the Pauli matrices sitting in the Gell-Mann ones, which never fails to puzzle mathematicians.

Consider the covariant derivative of the SM fundamental fermions, e.g. quarks,
$$
D_\mu -\partial_\mu = i g_{_{QCD}} \frac{\lambda}{2} \cdot G_\mu + i g \frac{\vec \tau}{2} \cdot \vec W_\mu  +i g ' \frac{ Y}{2}  B_\mu .
$$
Since the Hypercharge U(1) commutes with everything, its denominator 2 is immaterial but superfluous, and could be readily incorporated into its definition, $Y'\equiv Y/2 $, as most modern texts do, but not Cheng & Li — which, I understand, you are using. It is just there, here, to expedite trigonometry w.r.t. the SU(2) in the Weinberg angle. So, here, the hypercharge is *twice the average electric charge of the weak multiplet involved*, $Y=2(Q-T_3)$. (You could see why the modernists make faces at this sort of thing.)

Consider the **5** of SU(5), however,
$$
\psi = (d^{red},d^{green},d^{blue}, e^+, -\nu_e^c)_R,
$$
comprised out of the  colored down quark SU(2) singlet, and the conjugate doublet of leptons in this generation, so the R positron and its weak isopartner R neutrino.  Since you have 
$$
Y \psi= \operatorname {diag} (-2/3,-2/3,-2/3,1,1 ) \psi   ~~~~~\Longrightarrow \\
Q \psi= \operatorname {diag} (-1/3,-1/3,-1/3,1,0 ) \psi,
$$
it is evident *Y* is not normalized like, for instance,  the color matrices above.

Both *Y* and *Q* are traceless, of course.

So, normalize *Y* so that
$$
Y'' \equiv -\sqrt{3/5}\operatorname {diag} (-2/3,-2/3,-2/3,1,1) =-\sqrt{3/5} Y,
$$
and hence Tr$Y'' ~^2= 2$, just like the color or SU(2) generators.

It is manifest from the covariant derivative above that 
$$
g' Y = g_1 Y'', \Longrightarrow (g')^2= \frac {3}{5} g_1^2,
$$
leading to the celebrated SU(5) "initial constraint"; that is, at the UV point where $g_1=g_2\equiv g$, the weak mixing angle is constrained to
$$
\sin ^2 \theta_W= \frac{g'^2}{g^2+g'^2}=  \frac{3/5}{1+3/5}=3/8,
$$ 
which put that gleam in the eyes of its inceptors in the very first place!

Answer (score 0):

In [YM theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) a coupling constant $g\sim\sqrt{\alpha}$ sits next to the Lie algebra generator $T_a$, so the normalization of the coupling constant $g$ is directly correlated to the normalization of the Lie algebra generator $T_a$. The $3/5$ factor comes from the non-trivially embedding of the weak hypercharge $u(1)$ generator into the $su(5)$ GUT Lie algebra, cf. e.g. Ref. 1 and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313930/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; Eq. (69.8) and above eq. (84.12). A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html).