# Hypercharge and photon definitions in $SU(5)$ GUT

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, lie-algebra, electroweak, grand-unification

So, a weak isospin and hypercharge in $SU(5)$ are defined as
$$ T_3 = \frac{1}{2}diag(0,0,0,1,-1) $$
$$ Y = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}diag(-1/3,-1/3,-1/3,1/2,1/2) $$
The hypercharge already has the $\sqrt{3/5}$ factor in it, and normalized so that $tr(T_3^2)$ and $tr(Y^2)$ both equal to $1/2$.
Then why is this factor included in the definition of photon operators and the $Z$-boson?
After all, the fields $W^3$ and $B$ are already made of these $T_3$ and $Y$.

For example, i saw these definitions $$γ=B-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}W^3$$ and $$Z=B\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}+W^3.$$

Comment: You appreciate that (at the GUT scale) $\tan^2\theta_W\sim 3/5$, right? Eqn (5) [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Grand_unification#The_representations_for_scalars.2C_fermions.2C_and_gauge_fields).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes I know that. But what does it have to do with it?

Comment: Well, the "definitions" you "saw" (where?) are in weird normalizations, and signs of the Weinberg angle. You understand how to "translate" the [textbook answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle) into the corrected "definition" which diagonalizes the EW gauge boson mass matrix, right? Why don't you work it out and put it in your question for contrast?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/673845/gauge-boson-layout-in-rm-su5-gut-unification).

Comment: @CosmasZachos what is correct normalization? Is my definition of hypercharge generator right?

Comment: I meant normalization for the gauge bosons. Your Y is right, but in the "modern" half-scale convention. $Q=T_3+\sqrt{5/3} Y=\operatorname{diag}~(-1/3,-1/3,-1/3,1,0)$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos How does this answer the question? Rotation matrix of W and B contains sinw and cosw, which depend on scale.

Comment: Up to an overall normalization, of course. Look at the linked answer.

Comment: Well, for example, what is the value of the $sin_w^2$ at electroweak scale?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140652/discussion-between-cosmas-zachos-and-peter).