# $\mathbb{Z}_6$ symmetry in the Standard Model

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

It's a [well-known result](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9312254) that the spontaneous symmetry breaking of $SU(5)$ would lead not to the usual $G_{SM}=SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$, but to $G_{SM}/\mathbb{Z}_6$. However, it's also often argued that $G_{SM}/\mathbb{Z}_6$ (actually, also $G_{SM}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $G_{SM}/\mathbb{Z}_3$) would be indistinguishable from $G_{SM}$, since its effect is to *forbid left-handed fermions with zero hypercharge* (which were not seen experimentally and so wouldn't be a problem for the phenomenologist building his $G_{SM}$ from the ground up).

How can we demonstrate the statement in italic, and does the $\mod\mathbb{Z}_6$ symmetry play another role once integrated in the unified $SU(5)$? (in particular in connection with homotopy groups and possible magnetic monopoles)

Comment: I dont think the statement in italic is correct.  The /Z6 acts on the global property of the SM, and this is not equivalent to GSM/Z2 or GSM/Z3. See Huck's "Global structure of the standard model, anomalies, and charge quantization" and refs therein for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176518/2451 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149039/2451